# MySql query: what's the better way to get the number of unique pairs in a set?

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

There is a member_gorup table:

```
id    member_id    group_id
--    ---------    --------
1     23           17
2     23           17
3     23           13
4     24           17
5     24           5
6     25           13
```

What needs to be found is how many unique(distinct) member_ids each group_id has. In this case it is:

```
17 - 2
13 - 2
5  - 1
```

I managed to achieve this by using the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(`group_id`), `group_id` FROM 
  (SELECT `member_id`, `group_id` 
   FROM `member_groups` 
   GROUP BY `member_id`, `group_id`) AS `groups` 
GROUP BY `group_id`
```

Is there a way to achieve the same result without using the nested query - perhaps with DISTINCT?

(optional question: if so is it faster?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNT() has an optional DISTINCT syntax for exactly this kind of problem:

```
SELECT `group_id`, COUNT(DISTINCT `member_id`) AS count_members 
FROM `member_groups` 
GROUP BY `group_id`;
```

Comment: thanks, this query looks much better and it is not nested so I assume it is faster too.